# Conserve the action and execute after logging in - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

Consider this following scenario:

Suppose you are building an account-based application where you can access some parts of an application without having to log into an account. But, when the user wants to access that part of the application that needs to them to be logged in, we are directing to the `LoginViewController` and the user is now successfully logged in. There are multiple places where this is happening, and there is a single callback after the user is logged in: `didUserLoginSuccessfully`. Now, the problem here is, the user is expecting to resume whatever they were doing earlier, but to give them that experience,  we don't have that information -- the methods and variables to perform the operations when the user is logged in -- saved.

I solved this using the concept of blocks. Saving all the methods that were to be performed if the user is logged in inside a `block` variable and executing it in the login callback using `[block invoke]`.

Is this the right approach? Are there any better ways to do it?

Comment: There lots of ways to deal with this kind of issue, But first ill ask you, if its possible for you just to "PresentViewController" the "LogIn" ViewController on the current page. Then, when the user finished the procedure, you can just "Dissmiss" the Login controller, and you return to the same state.

Comment: Well, no. `LoginViewController` actually loads in an instance `UIWebView` where we are doing oauth2 Twitter integration. On successful login, we are delegating it to a `RootViewController`.

Comment: And what we are trying to achieve is conserve the "action" not the "state". Suppose you have click a button that says 'Save Article'. But you have to be logged in to save that article. So, my app redirects to twitter login. After successful login, the particular article has to be saved. See, "action" conserving!

Comment: Why not delegate back to the caller instead of hardcoding it to the RootViewController? You could also store where the user currently is and go back to that view, this would entail more code. Much easier, like @PiratM said to just present the view controller from the current view.

Comment: `RootViewController` is the caller. You want to save an article which is at the `RootViewController.` 
Y u no understand my problem? :(